# Values are not being saved to the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am pretty new to javascript and jquery. I currently have a xml file that I'm trying to parse by using jquery and javascript, but for some reason the values that I store on the array are not being saved.

```
var categories = new Array();  // Array for the categories

var data = {
  categories: []
};

var sources = [
{
  src:'',
  title: '',
  desc: ''
}];

var i = 0;

$.get('fakeFeed.xml', function (info) { 
  $(info).find("item").each(function () { 
     var el = $(this);
    var categoryName = el.find('category').text();
    var p = categories.indexOf(categoryName);

    sources[i] = [];
    sources[i].src = el.find('media\\:content, content').attr('url');
    sources[i].title = el.find("title").text();
    sources[i].desc = 'Moscone Center';

     if( p == -1) {
      categories.push(categoryName);
      var category = {
        name: categoryName,
        videos: []
      };
    }
    i++;
  }); 
});
```

If i do console.log(categories) it prints all the categories on the array but if I do console.log(categories.length) I keep getting 0...

```
console.log(categories.length); // This should be outputting 5 but I keep getting 0 for the size.
for (var i=0; i<categories.length; i++) {
  var category = {
    name: categories[i],
    videos: []
  };
}
```

I appreciate any help that anybody can give me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.get` function is asynchronous so you should try putting the logging inside the callback function.

```
$.get('fakeFeed.xml', function (info) { 
  $(info).find("item").each(function () { 
    ....
  }); 
  console.log(categories.length);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! so you're saying that other parts of the code may finish before the $.get function gets done going through the loop?

Comment: Yes. Because the code inside the `function(info) {...}` you pass in is , well, inside a function, that code is executed whenever `$.get` sees fit. The callback function might not even execute if the GET request to the XML file failed.